# i'm doing a script but i have an issue with page loading

Tags: php, status

I'm doing a website(in php) that shows if a game server is online or offline.
I've managed to figure something out and got it to work.
But the problem is if multiple servers are offline, the website takes 10-20 seconds to load.

Loads instantly if servers are online.

Is there a way i can make the website load instantly even if the servers are offline?

this is the main function.(the rest are ip's and server names.)

```
function pingDomain($domain){

    global $sport, $lport, $port, $l1, $l2;

    if ($domain == $l1){
        $port = $lport;
    }
    else if ($domain == $l2){
        $port = $lport;
    }
    else{
        $port = $sport;
    }

    $starttime = microtime(true);
    $file      = @fsockopen($domain, $port, $errno, $errstr, 1);
    $stoptime  = microtime(true);
    $status    = 0;

    if (!$file) $status = -1;  // Site is down
    else {
        fclose($file);
        $status = ($stoptime - $starttime) * 1000;
        $status = floor($status);
    }
    return $status;
}
```

Comment: this is probably due you have to wait for a timeout to say a server is offline. Would probably be a good idea to do the check with an AJAX call, so you can show a loading gif or something while the offline servers are checked, while the online ones will be show fast.

Comment: Use ajax. Start the page and after it finished loading start you asynchronous ajax calls. When they are finished refresh the server status on the page.

Comment: It didn't bother me but then i saw that similar websites don't have this problem.. and i can't fighure out how they did it.

Comment: @user2745790 If you don't like the AJAX way and/or you found some other service do this instantly without AJAX, a possible solution would be to check those server availability periodically from your server, save the status on your server and thus serving the webpage statically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a cron job in server and run this code every 1 minute, then save the result in database.
your live web site can load the servers status from database quickly, also use ajax to avoid from page refreshing.

Comment: i did the cron job/mysql way and it works perfectly... thanks for all your help guys... cheers